# Using "cursor with hold" on .NET towards SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net, db2, sql-server-2008-r2

In connection with a migration project, migrating data from DB2 to SQL Server I have run into a problem with the way the .NET provider towards DB2 uses (data) cursors.

Today the client is executing a set of .NET batch programs against DB2 using the ADO.NET provider from Host Integration Server 2010.

The programs are using a Db2Data reader to iterate over a cursor defined in a DB2 Package. In some cases the cursor is declared “**with hold**”, allowing the cursor to be left open after a commit have been made in the transaction scope.

The ADO.NET provider (`System.Data.SqlClient`) for SQL Server 2008 R2 does not support this feature.

Does anyone have any experience on “emulating” the desired behavior of the DB2 provider with regards to “cursor with hold”.

It should be noted that a re-implementation of the Stored Procedures using T-SQL cursors does not yield the desired effect, because a SQL Server ADO.NET data reader cannot interact with a T-SQL cursor the same way as the DB2 Provider and DB2 does today (this is at least our understanding).

Comment: why are you using cursors at all?

Comment: I would gladly do without cursors, if I could have the required functionality, i.e. continue to read from a resultset after a commit.

Comment: I have got this to work, however, before I spend time on writing up the solution, are anyone besides me actually interested?